Finding underlying data source in hover-map on website
I want to retrieve some of the data of this following site:
https://platform.elaad.io/interactieve-outlook/. More specifically, I am interested in the map with the current number of electric vehicles in the Amsterdam per district.
In order to do so, I looked at the inspect tool in Google Chrome. Here, I noticed by look in the network tab that the relevant information can be retrieve by using the following link structure:
https://data.elaad.io:8000/growth_scenarios/charging_points/mid/**district**/Buurt?municipality=**municipality**&min_year=2024&max_year=2050. For example, information for the district 'Centrum' in Amsterdam can be retrieved with: https://data.elaad.io:8000/growth_scenarios/charging_points/mid/Centrum/Buurt?municipality=Amsterdam&min_year=2024&max_year=2050
However, when trying to access the information for a district that contain a slash (e.g., Grunder/Koningshof), the link is broken. I tried to replace the slash with %2F (I noticed that spaces were replaced by %20), but this did not fix it.
Then, I returned to the website to explore further and I noticed that in the inspect tool, the call to these urls are also broken (error 404), resulting in unfound data to fill in the information on the district above the map. However, when I hover over district in the map itself, it is able to retrieve the data (see map). This makes me believe that the data is also retrieved in a different way to visualize it in the map.


Unfortunately, I can't make anything out out of the rest of the inspect tool (I tried to look at the console page there as well). Is there someone who could help me in understanding where the other data source is (if there is one), and how I can find this in the inspect tool.
